# How do I convert an old model propane fireplace to natural gas?

Tags: fireplace, gas, natural-gas

I installed a propane direct vent fireplace bought from Security Chimney International about 12 years ago.  I now want to convert it to natural gas.  I have phoned the company and they told me that the model is not being made any more so nothing is available but to check with a dealer.  A dealer close to where I live said the same thing.  What is involved in converting an old model fireplace from propane to natural gas?

Comment: This sounds like a "shop for me" question and not an actual how-to question.

Comment: I think the question needs to focus on what is involved in converting from propane to natural gas not how do you find the upgrade for your unit - which probably doesn't exist.  Pictures and description of what you have would help, including if you have natural gas in your home and where it is compared to fireplace.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the last part of your last sentence.  The natural gas is being hooked up to the house and a there will be connection to the fireplace.  The model of fireplace is Security Chimneys International PDV 33P.

Comment: What is involved seems to be a fair question. Google finds "Security Chimneys," and their fireplace products link takes you to Lennox. Lennox's web page (http://www.lennoxhearthproducts.com/owner-resources/literature/) includes manuals that describe the conversion process. I think most ship configured for natural gas, so perhaps you'll get lucky and find that when the installer converted, the removed orifices were left behind?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion kit usually consists of a different sized orifice to handle the LP fuel. I had to do this on my outdoor grill when I converted from LP to NG.